# How to echo a permalink in a conditional statement

Tags: wordpress, echo, permalinks

Hi I hope you can help me with some advice.

I set up a website with a blog. The excerpts are shown on category.php 
If there is content the excerpt is followed by a 'read more' link to the post. If there is nothing in content. It does not show 'read more'

To show this link I've written the following piece of code.

```
<?php
global $post;

if ( empty( $post->post_content ) ) {
    echo '';
} else {
echo '<p class="laes-mere"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">L&aelig;s mere...</a>     </p>';
}
?>
```

The 'read more'  (Læs mere...) shows up if there is content. This works exactly as I want it to. The problem is that the permalink does not work. I get this error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /< was not found on this server.

This is the page http://rubowarkitekter.dk/?cat=21
Any advice would be great. Thank you.

Ellen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have opened the php tags when  php tags are already  opened try this

```
echo '<p class="laes-mere"><a href="'.the_permalink().'">L&aelig;s mere...</a>     </p>';
```

You can also get the post link by using [**get_permalink**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

```
echo '<p class="laes-mere"><a href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID).'">L&aelig;s mere...</a>     </p>';
```

Comment: Dianuj thank you very much for your comment. I changed the code as you said. Now the link is just blank. The link doesn't take me anywhere.

Comment: This is the output `<p class="laes-mere">
<a href="">Læs mere...</a>
</p>` Could it be a problem with my single and double quotes?